# Redirect root to sub domain on IIS .NET Application

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET Application that is configured for root. But on my web server I want to run it on a sub domain like dash.site.com/app

So i would like all URLs such as /home.aspx to remap to /app/home.aspx. In my code i have references such as ../ this maps to root of the site whereas its an asp.net application that is hosting so ../ should point to the root of the application not the site hosting the application.

I believe this can be done in URL rewrite but could not find a regex to accomplish this.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?